# After Winter Bash is over, can we wear hats from past seasons?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash-2014

Winter Bash is fun and all, but after the event ends a few days of depression follows it since we can no long wear those hard earned hats (ever again).

**I would like to propose that all hats (from past seasons) become available for a brief period of time.**

This could happen right after Winter Bash ends, for a week, or for a couple of days during some special holiday during the year.

It would be so cool to enjoy past hats once again.

Comment: I miss my Boba Fett hat :/

Comment: Don't just -1, tell us why you don't like it.

Comment: It's not special if you can wear them forever.

Comment: It's not forever, it's just for a weekend.

Comment: You can do like [this user](http://stackoverflow.com/users/7311767/stephen-rauch): save your hats as images and use them as your avatar.

Answer (score 16):

The thing that makes the Winter Bash special is that the hats are only available for a limited time. If you really like a particular hat (or hats), take a screen shot of your avatar wearing it and save it for when you want to look stylish. (Note the dapper bow tie I'm sporting.)

Comment: I would love to be able to do that... I just can't ... because I didn't took screenshots last year... and now I can't wear them again. That's why is important to let us play with the hats from past seasons for a couple of days after Winter Bash is done.

Comment: @karlphillip There should be a sticker sheet for hats somewhere. Just take them into PhotoShop and squiggly-doo them.

Comment: @Compass You overestimate my artistic skills, young Padawan.

Comment: @karlphillip its the thought that counts, right?

Comment: @Compass [here is](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/2766716#2766716). Can I suggest eight hat from the left?

Comment: @SPArchaeologist I would totally wear that Gundam hat all day.